# OSError when importing python module talon

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to import talon but seem to get an OSError. I've tried updating numpy, sklearn and scipy. sklearn and scipy both fail to "build wheel". It's the same when trying to upgrade talon.

This is the error I get. when trying to import talon.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9dc622c182ae> in <module>()
      2 import scipy
      3 import sklearn
----> 4 import talon

C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec)

C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _load_backward_compatible(spec)

C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\talon-1.0.9-py3.5.egg\talon\__init__.py in <module>()
     17 
     18 if not os.path.isfile(EXTRACTOR_FILENAME):
---> 19     train_model()

C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\talon-1.0.9-py3.5.egg\talon\__init__.py in train_model()
     14 def train_model():
     15     """ retrain model and persist """
---> 16     train(init_classifier(), EXTRACTOR_DATA, EXTRACTOR_FILENAME)
     17 
     18 if not os.path.isfile(EXTRACTOR_FILENAME):

C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\talon-1.0.9-py3.5.egg\talon\signature\learning\classifier.py in train(classifier, train_data_filename, save_classifier_filename)
     18 def train(classifier, train_data_filename, save_classifier_filename=None):
     19     """Trains and saves classifier so that it could be easily loaded later."""
---> 20     file_data = genfromtxt(train_data_filename, delimiter=",")
     21     train_data, labels = file_data[:, :-1], file_data[:, -1]
     22     classifier.fit(train_data, labels)

C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in genfromtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, skip_header, skip_footer, converters, missing_values, filling_values, usecols, names, excludelist, deletechars, replace_space, autostrip, case_sensitive, defaultfmt, unpack, usemask, loose, invalid_raise, max_rows)
   1510                 fhd = iter(np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rbU'))
   1511             else:
-> 1512                 fhd = iter(np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rb'))
   1513             own_fhd = True
   1514         else:

C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py in open(path, mode, destpath)
    149 
    150     ds = DataSource(destpath)
--> 151     return ds.open(path, mode)
    152 
    153 

C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py in open(self, path, mode)
    499             return _file_openers[ext](found, mode=mode)
    500         else:
--> 501             raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
    502 
    503 

OSError: C:\Users\Tom\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\talon-1.0.9-py3.5.egg\talon\signature\data\train.data not found.
```

Comment: A file is missing. Try to reinstall `talon`.

Comment: I realised I had to manually reinstall rather than using pip. thanks